# Having "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" issue in Angular 8 after the first element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular 8 application that loads a list of buildings via http get request. The data is fetched correctly, but while displaying it, I get an error.

This is my component for displaying the components

```
  @Input() own: boolean;
  @Output() buildingChanged = new EventEmitter<Building>();
  buildings: Building[] = [];

  private searchText = '';

  constructor(private BuildingsService: BuildingService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadBuildings();
  }

  loadBuildings() {
    this.BuildingsService.getAllBuildings(this.own, this.searchText).subscribe(
      buildings => this.buildings = buildings);
  }

  clearSearchField() {
    this.searchText = '';
  }

  editBuilding(id: number) {
    // TODO
  }

  deleteBuilding(id: number) {
    // TODO
  }

  filterBuildings(value: string) {
    this.loadBuildings();
  }
}
```

below is my html file

```
    <mat-form-field >
      <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" #searchField (keydown.enter)="filterBuildings(searchField.value)" matInput
             placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" >
      <button mat-button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="clearSearchField()" *ngIf="searchField">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div *ngIf="buildings && buildings != undefined && buildings?.length > 0" >
  <div class="buildings-list" fxLayout="row"  fxLayoutGap="15px" fxlay>
    <mat-card *ngFor="let building of buildings" (click)="buildingChanged.emit(building)">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{building.name}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>{{building.floors.length}}</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{building.description}}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="editBuilding(building.id)">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          Edit
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="delete-button" (click)="deleteBuilding(building.id)">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          Delete
        </button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get following error message

```
BuildingListComponent.html:14 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (BuildingListComponent.html:14)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45294)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44594)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44272)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44594)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44272)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
```

But in the browser view, the first building is displayed correctly, every other building is not displayed and the error message is shown. The data is correctly assigned to the `buildings` variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is on line 14 in BuildingListComponent,html ?

Comment: can you paste your buildings json? And I suspect building.floors.length might be the problem...Please check you have floors for all the buildings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use safe navigation operator `?` everywhere  where you are using `.`  operator  to access the property of a object in (expect for model binding).

When Angular renders the view before project got a value assigned, it causes an exception. `?`. stops evaluating when project is `null` or `undefined`, which usually happens when data is fetched async, for example from the server which can take quite some time.

For example  her to solve the error:

```
    <mat-form-field >
      <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" #searchField (keydown.enter)="filterBuildings(searchField?.value)" matInput
             placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" >
      <button mat-button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="clearSearchField()" *ngIf="searchField">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div *ngIf="buildings && buildings != undefined && buildings?.length > 0" >
  <div class="buildings-list" fxLayout="row"  fxLayoutGap="15px" fxlay>
    <mat-card *ngFor="let building of buildings" (click)="buildingChanged.emit(building)">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{building?.name}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>{{building?.floors?.length}}</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{building?.description}}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="editBuilding(building?.id)">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          Edit
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="delete-button" (click)="deleteBuilding(building?.id)">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          Delete
        </button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it's something relatively new, I had to add the `?` operator after upgrade from `Angular 8` to `Angular 10`, before that it wasn't required.